# segue not going to destination controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

In my app I have a manually triggered push segue called "details". It is wired from the source controller to the destination controller and it's identifier is set. In my code I call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"details" sender:sender];
```

I can see the prepareForSegue function firing and have verified that the destination controller is of the proper type. I pass the destination controller a few bits of data it needs to display correctly. Oddly enough NOTHING happens. The app does not go to the destination controller.

Comment: Have you had any output in console? What kind of segue do you use push, modal?

Comment: Is self a navigation controller?

Comment: Assuming `self` is the current view controller, it seems like `sender` should be set to `self`. Is there a navigation controller? Push segues are for view controllers with a root navigation controller.

Comment: self is a view controller with a root navigation controller.

Comment: The segue is a push segue. Setting sender to self has no affect and really isn't mandatory to get a segue to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to look out for if you are having an issue with performSegueWithIdentifier while using a storyboard

- You have correctly hooked up your transitions in your Storyboard
- Your Segue Identifier matches the one on your Storyboard
- Your ViewController's class has not become deallocated
  (This can sometimes occur accidentally by calling from another class)
- Try setting sender to "self" rather than sender

Also, if you are planning on passing data between ViewControllers it is suggested that you use the prepareForSegue method, allowing you to pass values before segue'ing.